# Need help erasing/formatting the laptop to install a new OS

Tags: windows-xp

I have an old laptop which used to be my old office laptop. Its a corporate laptop so obviously I do not have admin rights. I have been trying to convert it to a personal laptop by erasing the windows (it has XP installed) and installing Ubuntu.

I have no clue what to do next. I tried to reboot in safe mode and create another admin account, but it would not let me. It asks admin password to go to the user accounts.

I cannot really download any software to install as it asks for admin password to proceed. Is there anything i can do?

Answer (score 1):

You can insert a bootable CD for Ubuntu.

Once you boot using this CD it will guide you through the installation process.  Because you are booting the CD, the current OS and administrator password aren't relevant.  Once you start to install, you'll get the option to wipe the disk entirely - and the admin account goes with it.

Comment: Thanks for the Reply Monk. 
i am confused though, and pardon my ignorance. SO for me to install ubuntu 12.04 LTS http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-desktop-long-term-support
i burn the installation .exe file into a CD, and put the CD into the laptop i want to format and just proceed with the instructions?

Comment: You need to download the .iso file and burn it onto a CD and while booting select CD as boot device. Also you can use the same iso file with a USB drive (its faster) https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick

Answer (score 1):

You don't need admin rights what-so-ever if you are wiping Windows and going 100% Ubuntu.  All you need to do:

1. Download the Ubuntu ISO [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download) (probably 32-bit for an old work computer)
2. Burn it to a CD/DVD (another option is a USB drive, but if you have any doubts - just default to CD/DVD)
3. Boot your computer, hit <kbd>Del</kbd> repeatedly during boot to enter the BIOS (May be an <kbd>F</kbd> key instead, there should be an alert during boot to tell you).
4. Find the "Boot Options" in your BIOS, set the CD/DVD drive as the default
5. Hit <kbd>f10</kbd> to `Exit and Save Changes` (verify that this is the same for you, in my experience it's always been so).
6. Your computer should automatically boot into Ubuntu, from there it is obvious what to do.  Select `Install` and follow the directions.  If you want to remove Windows fully, then select "Use entire drive for Ubuntu" or something similar at the partition editor, don't bother with the advanced mode...

Hopefully that gets you there.  That will wipe Windows and install Ubuntu if you follow the install prompts correctly, then you're an admin and will have lots to learn about Linux :).